# Postgres RANK() with ts_rank() returning same rank for all rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to return only the top N results for a query that utilizes ts_rank(). I do not know what N will be for each query, so I can not ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT X, because I don't know what X will be.

In my current approach, I use rank() in conjunction with ts_ranking and the result is that the ranking is always the same. How do I get the ranks to be different, based on the score returned by the ts_ranking? There should be two ranking groups of three names here: 1 and 2 (based on the score shown).

```
SELECT rank_filter.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        ts_rank(textsearchable_index_col, keywords) as score,
        rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ts_rank(textsearchable_index_col, keywords)
        ) as ranking
    FROM organization, to_tsquery('english', 'Obviously') keywords
    WHERE keywords @@ textsearchable_index_col ORDER BY score DESC
) as rank_filter;

          name          |   score   | ranking
------------------------+-----------+---------
 B-Obvious              | 0.0759909 |       1
 Obviously              | 0.0759909 |       1
 Obvious Engineering    | 0.0759909 |       1
 LexDex                 | 0.0607927 |       1
 Qualitest Turkey       | 0.0607927 |       1
 Obvious Software       | 0.0607927 |       1
```

The DESIRED output would be this:

```
         name          |   score   | ranking
-----------------------+-----------+---------
 B-Obvious              | 0.0759909 |       1
 Obviously              | 0.0759909 |       1
 Obvious Engineering    | 0.0759909 |       1
 LexDex                 | 0.0607927 |       2
 Qualitest Turkey       | 0.0607927 |       2
 Obvious Software       | 0.0607927 |       2
```

Comment: I think you want to `ORDER BY ts_rank(textsearchable_index_col, keywords)` not `PARTITION BY`.  Right now you're partitioning the rank based on the score so each score gets its own set of rankingss.  Since each score has its own ranking and you're using `rank` instead of `dense_rank` all of the rankings show up as 1 because each score is equal to the score it is partitioned by

Comment: @BShaps -- I'm getting closer now. Using dense_rank() in place of rank() and also replaced PARTITION BY with ORDER BY. Notable problem now is that the ranking is unexpectedly the inverse. 0.075 rows are ranking=2, and 0.060 rows are ranking=1. Any idea why?

Comment: @BShaps. I edited the question to provide the desired output. When I used rank(), I got the right groupings, but the 0.0759 scores were listing a ranking=13. I ultimately only want to grab ranking=1, and then I will deal with them elsewhere in the application.

Comment: I messed up my description of `dense_rank` in my previous post, it is actually what you want here, answer with the query done incoming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to both replace the `PARTITION BY` with `ORDER BY` and also use `dense_rank` instead of `rank`.  The following should work for your desired results:

```
SELECT rank_filter.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        ts_rank(textsearchable_index_col, keywords) as score,
        dense_rank() OVER (
            ORDER BY ts_rank(textsearchable_index_col, keywords) DESC
        ) as ranking
    FROM organization, to_tsquery('english', 'Obviously') keywords
    WHERE keywords @@ textsearchable_index_col ORDER BY score DESC
) as rank_filter;
```